# ie11 memory snapshot creation fails with 'out of memory' error

Tags: memory-leaks, internet-explorer-11, memory-profiling

When we try to take a memory snapshot in ie11's memory profiler (windows 10) We get an out of memory exception.

Is there a way to tell ie dev tools to use more memory? our computer has much more memory than is needed.

Comment: I'm having this same issue - did you have any luck finding a solution?

Answer (score 3):

Are you running the 64-bit version of IE (specifically, enable Enhanced Protected Mode and Use 64-bit Processes for EPM inside Tools > Internet Options > Advanced).

The problem is that 32bit processes cannot allocate more than ~300mb in a single allocation due to address-space fragmentation, no matter how much memory your PC has.

Comment: This is actually working in favor reducing memory leak in our app, I have read the blogs and all of them say that it provides better security because of Appcontainers, but other than that no mention of memory leak. So far we are using 32 bit IE, after enabling these two settings, IE starts using 64 bit process.